# Finding the input vector for minimizing a function

Tags: python

I have a large number of data points. For example, in the table below, x1, x2, x3 are inputs. Y is the output.
Inputs can take any fraction value. I want to estimate the input vector which minimizes the value of Y. For example, y is estimated to take a minimum of 13.9 @ (x1, x2, x3) = (0.1 , 0.95, 0.2).

Any help or nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

```
x1  x2  x3  y
0   0   0   15
0   0   1   15
0   1   0   14
0   1   1   18
1   0   0   20
1   0   1   19
1   1   0   21
1   1   1   15
```

Comment: This does not make any sense, Y=10 at (0,0,0) which is smaller than 13.9. Just take the min value of Y and you're done. I think some vital information is missing from the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, wrong example. I've changed the data. I'm trying to understand how you would approach this problem in general. It's that you do not have a well defined function, just a large number of data points. How do you estimate the function and its minima or maxima?

Comment: Well, my point still stands. Now the minima is at (0,1,0), isn't it? The function is defined by  these points, so it's just a matter of looping through them and select the min one.

Comment: If you generally, if you don't know the function, you only know that you have a series of points, the best way to estimate the minimum would be to use a gradient descent (assuming your function is convex). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent However in your particular case finding the value associated ti the minimun of y should work

Comment: What is the number of data points? How "funky" is your function? How many extrema do you expect? For each set of points, there is an infinite amount of possible underlying functions, thus answering these questions is vital. Generally, I guess you're looking for interpolation, e.g. [using pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is defined by specific points, you can just pick the coordinate with the minimum value. The function cannot take any lower value without further assumptions about the function. Example in [numpy](https://numpy.org/) below

```py
import numpy as np
data = """0   0   0   15
0   0   1   15
0   1   0   14
0   1   1   18
1   0   0   20
1   0   1   19
1   1   0   21
1   1   1   15"""
A = np.array([line.split() for line in data.splitlines()]).astype(float)
A[np.argmin(A[:, 3]), :]
```

Will print `array([ 0.,  1.,  0., 14.])` which is the point where the function takes it's minimum value.